# What framework can be used to generate a sequence of PNGs from a javascript/WebGL animation?

Tags: javascript, png, webgl

I have a few WebGL animations like http://www.purplefrog.com/~thoth/art/twinkle-webgl/twinkle.html and I'd like to turn them into encoded videos that don't require a browser.

I know how to take a "snapshot" of a canvas in firefox using toDataURL(), but I only know how to manually save the resulting image.  Doing this for hundreds of frames just is not practical.

Is there an existing framework that I could use where all I have to do is tweak my webgl's rendering loop to save PNGs automatically?

Comment: [Asking for libraries/frameworks is off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for stackoverflow

Answer (score -1):

While this is not a proper answer to the question, I have managed to come up with a slightly different form of brute force.

I have a button and a hyperlink on the web page:

```
<button onclick="var s=10, o=0; build_animation(frame_to_canvas_function,[o*s*30, (o+1)*s*30], document.getElementById('animation'))">save</button>
<a id="animation">animation</a>
```

I have javascript which iterates through rendered canvases and uses `toDataURL()` to get the PNG bytes from them, and uses a version of https://github.com/beatgammit/tar-js (modified to work in a browser instead of Node.js) to build a tar file in RAM.  I then use the Blob API's `createObjectURL()` to turn that tar file into a URL that I attach to the hyperlink.

```
function payloadFromDataURI(uri)
{
    // assumes it is base64 encoded
    var idx = uri.indexOf(',')
    var str = atob(uri.substring(idx+1))
    var rval = new Uint8Array(str.length)
    for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    rval[i] = str.charCodeAt(i)
    }
    return rval
}

function rawToDataURI(uint8a, len, mime)
{
    if (1) {
    var blob = new Blob([ uint8a.subarray(0,len) ], {type:"application/tar"})
    return URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    }

    // this code below can blow out your RAM pretty easily

    var rval = "data:"+mime+";base64,"
    var block_size=1024
    var raw=""
    for (var cursor=0; cursor < len; cursor += block_size) {
    var n = Math.min(block_size, len-cursor)
    raw += String.fromCharCode.apply(null, uint8a.subarray(cursor, cursor+n))
    //console.log([cursor, len, block_size, raw.length, n])
    }
    //console.log(raw.length)
    rval += btoa(raw)
    //console.log(rval.length)
    return rval
}


/**
This function renders several frames of a javascript <canvas>
animation and turns them into a downloadable (in-RAM) tar blob.

   frame_to_canvas_function is a function that takes a frame number as
   an argument and returns the <canvas> element into which the frame
   has been rendered.

   nFrames is how many frames we render (numbered 0..(nFrames-1) ) .
   Optionally, it can be an array of [start,afterLast] if you want to
   render a different range of frames.  I find I need the array form
   if I want to render more than 400 frames at 1080p because if you
   try to do them all in one go you can exhaust your browser's RAM.

   a_elt is the <a> element whose href will be set to the blob URI of
   the tar file that gets generated.
*/
function build_animation(frame_to_canvas_function, nFrames, a_elt)
{
    var start = new Date().getTime()
    var tape = new Tar()

    var first=0
    var afterLast=nFrames
    if (nFrames instanceof Array) {
    first=nFrames[0]
    afterLast = nFrames[1]
    }

    for (var i=first; i<afterLast; i++) {

    var frame = frame_to_canvas_function(i).toDataURL()

    var payload = payloadFromDataURI(frame)
    tape.append("frame"+i+".png", payload)
    console.log("frame "+i)
    }

    a_elt.setAttribute("href", rawToDataURI(tape.out, tape.written, "application/tar"))

    var elapsed =  ( new Date().getTime() ) - start

    console.log("download link ready "+elapsed+"ms ; "+tape.written+" bytes")
}
```

The missing piece is the `frame_to_canvas_function()` which looks like

```
function frame_to_canvas_function(frame)
{
    var canvas = uvSquare.element
    canvas.width = 1920
    canvas.height = 1080

    triggerSnapshot=1 // lazy way to rig the drawing buffer for preservation

    var fps = 30
    uvSquare.drawPictureInner((frame+771)*1000 / fps)

    return uvSquare.element
}
```

because most of my animations use milliseconds I translate the frame number into a milliseconds value and pass it into the draw function.

While it is less brutal than saving each PNG frame one at a time, it is still somewhat brutal.  Depending on how well each frame compresses I can get 3-10 seconds worth of video at a time (trying to build too big a tar file crashes firefox).  It does take a couple of minutes to shovel all these bytes, and firefox becomes non-interactive while it is computing (and pops up warnings about runaway javascript for you to click "Continue" on).

It would not surprise me if there were overlooked optimizations and improvements possible throughout this Rube Goldberg machine.

I do not consider this a proper answer to my question because most animations require me to edit the frame range and save multiple tar files.  A proper answer would be able to render and store thousands of frames without ongoing user input.